404 Not Found Error on Render Deployment for React Vite App, Works Locally
I am experiencing an issue where my React Vite application works perfectly fine locally, but when I deploy it on Render, I get a 404 (Not Found) error for certain routes. Here are the details:
Project Setup:

React
Vite
Deployment on Render

Steps to Reproduce:

Run the app locally using npm run dev - everything works as expected.
Deploy the app to Render.
Access the deployed app - the home page loads fine, but navigating to any other route directly (e.g., refreshing the page or accessing via URL) results in a 404 error.

Impact on Password Reset:
This issue is causing emailed password reset links to become 404, making it impossible for users to reset their passwords.
